# AngularJS - ng-model not selecting any select option - Impossible to access data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, rest, laravel

I am beginning using Angular and try to make a simple edit form in order to interact with restful apis.

I deal with a problem for a few hours now... Angular does not populate well my form when dealing with select options. It seems to be a type problem.

[image: Image capture of the form]

Sources are available on github here: https://github.com/GloomySpark/website

It's a Laravel / Angular App... The concerned files should be
`/tree/master/public/assets/js/angular/admin`

and

`/blob/master/public/views/category/admin/edit.html`

Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: It would help if you post the sections of the code like the HTML and the JS controller instead of asking us to go fetching 

Comment: From my point of view you should separate laravel and angular code. And instead use laravel as an API/webservices ;)

Comment: It is exactly what I do. Could you point some code where your statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using `ng-repeat` to create select options. It's better to use `ng-options` instead. Here is small simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amighty/syorkefg/) with ng-options syntax.

Please try something like below,

```
<select name="state" id="category_state" class="form-control" ng-model="category.category.state_id" required ng-options="state.id as state.slug for state in states">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answerr

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching, I found the reason why this was not ok. 
As mentioned, I also tried with ng-options which was not doing the right way but if somebody knows how to use this solution, feel free to comment...

The problem was due to the fact that category.state is an object and because I wanted to make it equal with state_id which is a number.

The solution I found is the following:

```
        <select id="state_id" name="state_id" class="form-control" ng-model="category.state_id">
            <option ng-selected="category.state_id==state.id" ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{ state.id }}">{{ 'state.'+state.slug | i18n }}</option>
        </select>
```